# Ajax navigation and scripts loaded only on certain pages

Tags: ajax, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I'm building a theme. The theme post navigation is done through jQuery Ajax.
I've been several plugins to see compatibility and I have a problem with the Ajax functionallity.

Some plugins such as Jetpack, load certain scripts depending on the post content.Say for example Page1 has no post with VideoPress functionallity and Page2 does. Then scripts necessary will be loaded on Page2 **only**. I get into a problem as the user might go to Page1, then Page2 posts will load through Ajax and the Video post (from Page2) will break as the scripts were not loaded at first on Page 1.

Is there a way to solve this? I'm quite lost on how to.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugins are nice about it and [register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) all of their scripts upfront, and then just [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) them as needed, you should be able to enqueue all of them to load all the time. Find out the handles they were registered with and enqueue them.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script('example-handle');
    wp_enqueue_script('another-example-handle');
}, 20);
```

However, some plugins register scripts through the `wp_enqueue_script()` function even when they conditionally load them. For those, you will need to copy those enqueue statements and modify the paths to the scripts so that they'll load correctly.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', function() {
    $url = plugins_url('js/example.js', 'example-plugin/x');
    wp_enqueue_script('example-handle', $url /* and any other params they had */);
}, 20);
```

Comment: But this means I have to check manually for the enqueue right?

Comment: You'll need to search the code of your plugins to find the scripts and stylesheets they enqueue, then enqueue them all in anticipation that they'll be needed.